# How to make multi layer cross tabs in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, crosstab

I am attempting to create a multi-layered cross tab in R. Currently, when using this code:

```
NewMexico_DEM_xtab_ <- NewMexico_DEM_Voterfile %>%
  group_by(Sex, CountyName) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(Sex, n)
```

I receive this output:

[image]

My goal is to add a layer for age using the Age column and for R to output a tab like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can do this with my current code or a package that would make this easier?

Comment: Hey do you need the data file? The column names that are being worked with are Sex, CountyName, and Age. When making a cross tab with the two variables, it produces the table in my first picture. How would I add Age to this so it sorts age at the top level in ranges that I choose, then gender?

Comment: I'll add `ftable(iris_df, col.vars=c("Age", "Sample"), row.vars="Species")` as a possible alternative, though it's not *dplyr*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do either of these approaches solve your problem?

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Create sample data
iris_df <- iris
iris_df$Sample <- sample(c("M","F"), 150, replace = TRUE)

# crosstabs
iris_df %>%
  group_by(Species, Sample) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(Sample, n)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species        F     M
#>   <fct>      <int> <int>
#> 1 setosa        26    24
#> 2 versicolor    25    25
#> 3 virginica     27    23

# Add in 'Age'
iris_df$Age <- sample(c("18-24", "25-35", "36-45", "45+"), 150, replace = TRUE)

# crosstabs
iris_df %>%
  group_by(Species, Sample, Age) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(Age, n)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   Species, Sample [6]
#>   Species    Sample `18-24` `25-35` `36-45` `45+`
#>   <fct>      <chr>    <int>   <int>   <int> <int>
#> 1 setosa     F            2       4      14     6
#> 2 setosa     M           11       4       5     4
#> 3 versicolor F            3       8       8     6
#> 4 versicolor M            5       8       2    10
#> 5 virginica  F            5       8       7     7
#> 6 virginica  M            6      10       3     4

# Using janitor::tabyl()
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test
iris_df %>%
  tabyl(Species, Sample, Age)
#> $`18-24`
#>     Species F  M
#>      setosa 2 11
#>  versicolor 3  5
#>   virginica 5  6
#> 
#> $`25-35`
#>     Species F  M
#>      setosa 4  4
#>  versicolor 8  8
#>   virginica 8 10
#> 
#> $`36-45`
#>     Species  F M
#>      setosa 14 5
#>  versicolor  8 2
#>   virginica  7 3
#> 
#> $`45+`
#>     Species F  M
#>      setosa 6  4
#>  versicolor 6 10
#>   virginica 7  4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>